# How to address JSHint warnings that functions are not defined when there are many externally defined functions

Tags: javascript, jshint

This often asked question is usually answered by stating that each JavaScript file should configure the externally defined globals that it uses in the JSHint configuration.

In my case I have library files that define several hundred functions. I have many other files that call functions from those libraries.

It would be difficult to maintain copying and pasting the name of every library function into the JSHint configuration.

Is there a more maintainable way of addressing this warning?

1. Is there some method of combining a file with its library files before linting them?
2. Is there an alternate tool which addresses this problem?
3. Is there an approach for creating or using JavaScript libraries that eliminates the need to answer this question?

Ideally any answers to this questions will work with an Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: John, if there're hundreds of warnings on using 'outer' variables in your JS files, I guess you should change something in a way you write and maintain your JS code. Please check out Browserify http://browserify.org/

Comment: @gothy I would love to do so. I am curious what method people use to organize reusable functions rather than placing their library functions in separate library files.

Comment: you can read few tutorials on this. Start with http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/ for example

Comment: @gothy Thank you. My understanding is that Browserify is a great solution for node.js but I am not using node.js. These JavaScript files are solely used in browsers.

Comment: no it's a way to structure your front-end code as CommonJS modules(similarly to node apps). 
You can also try to use ES6 Modules with a code transpiler like Babel http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#modules

Comment: @JohnCashew If you ask a question and get an answer I would **highly** recommend you actually check it out before rejecting it based on faulty assumptions. Please go back to the "browserify" link **and read it**. Just the first sentence already is enough to question your response.

Comment: @someone thank you for the feedback. In this case it is clear from that document that Browserify requires node.js however only at compile time. I like Browserify and Babel, however it doesn't seem like either of these will help solve my JavaScript linting problem because I would need to run JSHint on the output of the transpilation which would not be visible in an IDE such as Eclipse.

Comment: Are your functions in a flat namespace? Because only then do you have that problem. Functions from external files should be in their namespace - and then you can simply add the one or few prefixes to the `globals` for jshint. So do you have `myFunction()` after import or do you have `MaNameSpace.myFunction()`? You should have the latter.

Comment: They are not in a namespace. As you say, moving them into a namespace will achieve the immediate goal of eliminating the JSHint warnings. However it blocks the long term goal of the linter validating that the function calls refer to real functions. Maybe there is a more holistic way of linting all the JavaScript files than using JSLint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the [`globals`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals) option.

In the case that there are scores of globals which cannot be manually managed, the best approach would be to either namespace them or to automate the authoring of the JSHint configuration.

### Namespacing

With namespacing, akin to having classes with static methods, you can group related globals as references on a single object. I believe that in modern compilers you should expect to see some performance improvements when resolving the associated references on said objects.

```
var gardening = (function () {
   var exports = {};
   exports.water = function () {};

   function till () {};
   exports.till = till;

   return exports;
})();

var debug = {
   prettyPrint: function (obj) {}
   inspect: function () {}
};
```

So, as opposed to having a blob of several dozen shoulder-to-shoulder  globals, you can extract a few objects under which to group the references. Creating such hierarchies supports the brain's aptitude to construct tree-like resolutions for functions which are related in their purpose.

### Dynamically authoring your JSHint configuration

If you already have some task runner implemented for your project (and you probably do), then it wouldn't hurt to add some custom task for aggregating globals from source files when these can be counted in scores and cannot be reasonably managed with a manual approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// ./task.js
var fs = require('fs');

// Some pre-defined JSHint options
var jsHintOptions = {
   maxerr: 10,
   bitwise: true,
   globals: {
       foo: true,
       bar: false
   }
}

var cmd = process.argv[2];
if (cmd === 'author-jshintrc') authorJsHintRc();

// Hammer time!
function authorJsHintRc() {
    var globals = [];
    // Some fancy regular expression which can match
    // the globals from your sources
    var reMatchGlobal = /^\s+function\s([\w\d_]+)/gm;

    var extractGlobals = function (name) {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(name).toString();
        var matches = contents.match(reMatchGlobal);
        globals.push.apply(globals, matches);
    }

    var registerGlobal = function (global) {
        jsHintOptions.globals[global] = false;
    }

    // These are our problematic source files which contain
    // too many globals to specify manually
    [
        'path/to/foo.js', 
        'path/to/bar.js'
    ].forEach(extractGlobals);

    // Extend the jsHintOptions with the dynamically resolved globals
    globals.forEach(registerGlobal);

    // Author the project's .jshintrc
    fs.writeFileSync('.jshintrc', JSON.stringify(jsHintOptions));
}
```

Ideally, dropping or extending the  `.jshintrc` in your project root should mean these options are introspected by the Eclipse JSHint plugin and the project JSHint errors should immediately go away.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. In my question I explained that the problem with using your suggested approach is that I would need to copy and paste hundreds of function names into this configuration setting. I am searching for a more maintainable solution.

Comment: Sorry for overlooking such an important detail. I'll try to edit my answer with some possible approaches.